# A lot of queries get suspended. What should I do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I'm handling an application used by around 2000 people. Everyday users insert around 300 rows/user at the same time (around 7 am to 11 am). I handle it using stored procedures that contain only insert statements, but I use `begin tran` to prevent the primary key getting duplicate.

Currently suspended transactions frequently happen, so my stored procedure takes around 1-2minutes to be done and this causes our users to wait for a long time to insert every data.
I already checked:

1. Disk speed normal around read : 600mb/s write 744mb/s.
2. Procesor usage between 20 - 40 % with 10 cores.
3. Memory usage only 6gb, I used 12gb of memory.
4. Check from `sys.dm_exec_requests`,`sp_who2`, and `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`.

   Result from number 3 is I found that my stored procedure suspends each other (same stored procedures different executor)

This is my stored procedures (Sorry, for the naming, because it is confidential for my company):

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_DESTIONATION_TABLE_INSERT]
    {params}
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN   
    BEGIN TRAN InsertT
    
    DECLARE @ERRORNMBR INT
    
    SET @ERRORNMBR = 0

    IF @T = ''
    BEGIN   
        -------------------------------------------------
        DECLARE @TCID VARCHAR(15)

        SELECT @TCID = ID
        FROM DESTIONATION_TABLE 
        WHERE   NIK = @NIK AND
                CUSTOMERID = @CUSTOMERID AND 
                    CUSTOMERTYPE = @CUSTOMERTYPE AND --edit NvA 20180111
                DATEDIFF(day,DATE,@DATE) = 0

        --IF THERE IS ALREADY A CALL IN SERVER
        IF @TCID IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            IF @INTERFACE <> 'WEB' BEGIN
                --GET EXISTING CALL ID
                SET @ID = @TCID

                BEGIN TRAN UBAH
                UPDATE DESTIONATION_TABLE
                SET 
                    columns=value
                WHERE ID = @ID
                    AND employeeid = @employeeid
                    AND CUSTOMERID = @CUSTOMERID 

                SET @ERRORNMBR = @ERRORNMBR + @@ERROR
                IF @ERRORNMBR = 0
                BEGIN
                    COMMIT TRAN UBAH
                    SELECT 
                        columns
                    FROM DESTIONATION_TABLE WHERE ID = @ID
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRAN UBAH
                END 
            END
            COMMIT TRAN InsertT
            RETURN
        END
        --------------------------------------------------

        -- CHECK @DEVICECONTROLID
        IF @DEVICECONTROLID IS NOT NULL
            AND @INTERFACE <> 'WEB' 
            AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DESTIONATION_TABLE WHERE DEVICECONTROLID = @DEVICECONTROLID)
        BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DESTIONATION_TABLE_TEMP WHERE DEVICECONTROLID = @DEVICECONTROLID)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO DESTIONATION_TABLE_TEMP
                       (COLUMNS)
                 VALUES
                       (VALUES)
            END
                        
            SELECT * FROM DESTIONATION_TABLE WHERE _DEVICECONTROLID = @_DEVICECONTROLID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN   
            some logic to make primary key formula{string+date+employeeid+increment}
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRAN UBAH

        IF @PARAMS = 'WEB' 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE DESTIONATION_TABLE
            SET 
                COLUMNS = PARAMS
            WHERE ID = @ID
        END
        ELSE IF PARAMS = 'MOBILE'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE DESTIONATION_TABLE
            SET 
                COLUMNS = PARAMS
            WHERE ID = ID
        END

        SET @ERRORNMBR = @ERRORNMBR + @@ERROR
        
        IF @ERRORNMBR = 0
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRAN UBAH
            SELECT 
                COLUMNS
             FROM DESTIONATION_TABLE WHERE ID = ID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN UBAH
        END
    END

    COMMIT TRAN InsertT


END
```

[image]

I need a suggestion, what should I check next to get what's wrong with my server is.

Is `begin tran` is the issue here?

Comment: Can you share what the procedure looks like

Comment: already attached my queries for stored procedure

Comment: I think you are making this proc do too much, it needs to be lean, **1.** your application calling it should have the `@TCID` available, why can't it pass it to the proc? **2.** When you update why are you adding the `@employeeid` and `@CUSTOMERID` to the where clause? The query before it you used to `@employeeid` and `@CUSTOMERID` to get `@TCID`? **3.** Your primary key design needs to be replaced with a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) 4. Why can't the application calling the proc handle the errors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but a googling of "BEGIN TRAN" seems to show that it "locks a table until the transaction is committed with a "COMMIT TRAN" ... meaning that it is a blocking process. So if you're table is locked when all these inserts are attempting to execute, some of them would obviously not be successful.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3305/what-does-begin-tran-rollback-tran-and-commit-tran-mean/

I would suggest building a work queue on its own thread that listens for INSERTS/UPDATES. Then the queue can empty into the DB at it's leisure.